# 403 Forbidden: Session not accepted while playing video using wrench module on wowza

Tags: server, video-streaming, wowza, wowza-transcoder, wrench

I have installed a Wrench module on Wowza streaming engine. Now, I have created a new production environment to play video. But it showing 403 forbidden error. And on error log, it showing session not accepted. It is working fine in current production but not working on a newly created production environment. Videos are playing without wrench on the new production environment.

Following is the error log image link:-

https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/78KisuWmqkNYapL9ShEUW6ubDvixH-TTnV6nmW8SoKO0GtSIf4DMl1ZmZUoCi4OqaTXfIge4MIZxpfmJDblxBoTekog

https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/6dwMFaA5tXbfnXVTU-EJQKmitkhJLcj7kH_QhH291iBLj8YJWXnbr2Cm4HDDThBAR_Apf9l3NFkcczE1sNNzdbcEUo1N

Comment: Hi, I'm sorry, but I can't read the text on those images. Can you share the full logs in a readable format?

Comment: @jabal https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/7S3o-Iz1hStTs1HgFXbioCJBzrQsCGoAUJTiDvEudSq5rzz014QIviWGk7q2i6ZVxXFh3xaTWAcyy5MAWmtR9yxJ7Mo             https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/HwoetvsbOEra-WSNwu_tkrVXl1N9-3ECvbW0PnoutXe9Sn25MyHdI5DFUECP9GiOfTZLRcMhdAFco4h1Bk27PuITVco

Comment: I can only help if you give me the full logs including Wrench and Wowza starting messages

Comment: If you mean the Wrench module of https://streamtoolbox.com; then I recommend to contact the developer via help@streamtoolbox.com